# php download all images of webpage from link

Tags: php, curl

When i download the html using curl or file_get_contents I don't get the <img scr=....
It's a matter with the fact that images appear after some delay? here is the site: https://www.tumbex.com/memes.tumblr/posts?page=2

and code (first try)

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.tumbex.com/memes.tumblr/posts?page=2');
```

and code (second try)

```
$html = get_dataa('https://www.tumbex.com/memes.tumblr/posts?page=2');

    echo($html);

function get_dataa($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: That page appears to be running JavaScript to update the UI.  Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools to see all the requests it's making.  Reverse-engineering it to scrape its data it going to be a bit more involved than just grabbing the initial HTML.

Comment: To see what that page looks like to curl, disable JavaScript and reload that page.  To solve this, you may need to go through reading and understanding this: [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).

Answer (score 0):

just press *F12* on your chrome, then go to Network tab.
there find the api url of tumbex, then copy that with the request header.

if done,
you can use curl to that url *(api url)* to get response..
this my code

```
<?php
$page = 1; //change number of page here
$url = "https://api.1.tumbex.com/api/tumblr/posts?tumblr=memes&type=posts&page=$page&tag=";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
    'Accept: */*',
    'Authorization: Bearer 0fae0f237b33e781a6884295b39c6e903484ef1ee3190bd51f07dd9881bdccbd',
    'content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Referer: https://www.tumbex.com/',
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token: MVMyb2hLTWtQdEJEYjJ0SER1dEwvZz09',
    'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$res = curl_exec($ch); //result is json

$json = json_decode($res, true);
$edan = $json['response']['posts'];

for($i=0; $i<count($edan); $i++){

    $get_post       = $edan[$i];
    $type           = $get_post['detected_type']; //get type

    //$get_photo = $get_post['blocks'][0]['content'][0]['hd'];  -> get image url
    //$get_video = $get_post['blocks'][0]['content'][0]['media']['url']; -> get video url
    //$get_text1 = $get_post['blocks'][0]['content'][0]['text']; -> get text 1
    //$get_text2 = $get_post['blocks'][0]['content'][1]['text']; -> get text 2

    if($type == 'photo'){
        $get_photo  = $get_post['blocks'][0]['content'][0]['hd'];
        echo "<img src='".$get_photo."' height='120' width='160'><br>";
    }

}
```

You must know, the **bearer token** and **x-csrf-token** always changing
if the result is blank, that means the **Bearer token** and **x-csrf-token** has expired
But, You can solve that manually or use other curl to auto-fetch the **bearer token** and **x-csrf-token**..

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I tried it and it does not work. $res is empty, and how did you get to that link?

Comment: @thepepp read again, "You must know, the bearer token and x-csrf-token always changing
if the result is blank, that means the Bearer token and x-csrf-token has expired
But, You can solve that manually or use other curl to auto-fetch the bearer token and x-csrf-token.."

Comment: sorry, I'm a noob. where are bearer token and x-csrf-token stored? And also I still don't know how you got to the link https://api.1.tumbex.com/api/tumblr/posts?tumblr=memes&type=posts&page=$page&tag=